# Error (10327): VHDL error: can't determine definition of operator ""="" -- found 0 possible definitions

Tags: vhdl

I have many errors despite trying different ways of typing my program, but most time using logical thinking. The thing is, I have never tried combining different things together before, thus having this problem of not being able to compile it. There is quite a requirement and I can process it logically, but need help with the coding. Is it ok to guide me? Thank you.

The attached code below is not the completed one, but it already has a lot of errors.

```
library ieee;   
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity tracking7 is
port    (   sensor      :  in  std_logic;
            reset_bar   :  in  std_logic;
            D3, D2, D1, D0          :  in std_logic;
            q           :  out std_logic;
            led         : out std_logic;
            a4,b4,c4,d4,e4,f4,g4 : out std_logic);
end tracking7;


architecture flow of tracking7 is

signal input  : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);      --VECTORS FOR INTERNAL 
signal output : std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);    --USE IN DECODER STATEMENTS
signal count_sig: unsigned (3 downto 0); 

begin
    input <= (D3, D2 , D1, D0);
WITH input SELECT
  output <=     "0000001" when "0000",    --DISPLAY 0
                "1001111" when "0001",    --DISPLAY 1
                "0010010" when "0010",    --DISPLAY 2
                "0000110" when "0011",    --DISPLAY 3
                "1001100" when "0100",    --DISPLAY 4
                "0100100" when "0101",    --DISPLAY 5
                "0100000" when "0110",    --DISPLAY 6
                "0001111" when "0111",    --DISPLAY 7
                "0000000" when "1000",    --DISPLAY 8
                "0000100" when "1001",    --DISPLAY 9
                "0001000" when "1010",    --DISPLAY A
                "1100000" when "1011",    --DISPLAY B
                "0110001" when "1100",    --DISPLAY C
                "1000100" when "1101",    --DISPLAY D
                "0110000" when "1110",    --DISPLAY E
                "0111000" when "1111",    --DISPLAY F
                "1111111" when others;    --BLANK DISPLAY
                        

 
    process ( sensor, reset_bar) 
    begin 
        if (reset_bar = '1')    then            count_sig <= count_sig; 

    elsif  falling_edge (sensor) then if (count_sig = D3& D2& D1& D0) then  
            count_sig <= "0000"; 
            else  
            count_sig <= count_sig + 1; 
        end if;  
        end if;         
    end process; 

    
    process (D3, D2, D1, D0)
        begin
          if (q = D3&D2&D1&D0)
            then led <= '1'; --LED light up when reach ref no
          else
            led<= '0';
        
        end if;
        end process;

  a4 <= output(6);
  b4 <= output(5);
  c4 <= output(4);
  d4 <= output(3);
  e4 <= output(2);
  f4 <= output(1);
  g4 <= output(0);
        
q <= std_logic_vector (count_sig);

end flow;
```

Maybe a brief note on what my code is about, basically to design the inventory management system that detects the number of uniforms
returned to the dropbox. The user can set any number of uniforms he wants to detect on
inputs: D3D2D1D0. Design a system with the following specifications-

1. Once the reference number is reached, a LED turns on and the count stops at
   the reference number even if input sensor is activated. Show the number of
   uniforms detected on a seven-segment display and the value of the reference
   on another display.
   Eg: If the reference number is 15
2. When reset is activated, the led and seven segments should reflect the latest
   status of uniforms detected.

Please advise!

Comment: Hello Arthur and welcome on StackOverflow. When asking for help please specify what tools you are using (including version, if you know it), show what commands you use and what error messages you get. Guessing all this from your source code is too much work. But the very first thing to do could be to visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially the section about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is.

Comment: For this supposedly Boolean expression `q = D3&D2&D1&D0`, there isn't an equality operator that can test between a left hand operand with a base type of std_ulogic and a right hand operand of an unknown array type with a base element type of std_ulogic. Perhaps those concatenation operators wanted to be AND operators?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `q = D3&D2&D1&D0` is not valid. The & character performs concatenation in VHDL so you are actually attempting to compare a std_logic type with a four bit signal. This is illegal in VHDL. You need to use the and keyword to combine the signals together instead. However, this needs to be done outside of the expression in the if statement. Something like this should work:

```
and_d <= D3 and D2 and D1 and D0;

process (and_q) is
begin
  if (q = and_d) then
    led <= '1'; --LED light up when reach ref no
  else
    led <= '0';
  end if;
end process;
```

You could also use a variable inside of the process block to combine the Dn bits:

```
process (D3, D2, D1, D0) is
  variable and_q : std_logic;
begin
  and_q := D3 and D2 and D1 and D0;
  if (q = and_d) then
    led <= '1'; --LED light up when reach ref no
  else
    led <= '0';
  end if;
end process;
```